# SQL database not compiling

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-ce

I am a C# beginner and I am trying to learn some things about using data bases but it is such a HASSLE. I am not entierly sure what I am doing but I'll try to describe my problem as best I can.

I am coding in visual studio and I am also using SQL server 2014. I have created my own database from which I want to get information from. What I want is to get the information from the database and then simply displaying the data stored in the database in a console application.

I get a strange error message when I try to compile.

> An unhandled exceptio of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occured in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll

I have added the `System.Data.SqlServerCe` reference in my project, but it still seems like it won't work. I also added using `System.Data` as well as using `System.Data.SqlServerCe`.

This is the code in my application.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string conStr = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\ShippingData.mdf";
        SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conStr);
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1", con);
        SqlCeDataAdapter adapt = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapt.Fill(ds, "Table1");

        foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(row[column]);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: What line do you get the error on? Is there an `InnerException`?

Comment: I get the error at adapt.Fill(ds, "Table1");

Comment: You do not have a problem with databases, and you are not new to C# - you have zero experience in baseline programming. And hate reading. For example the MESSAGE in the exception, which I am sure would be a nice explanation what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2014 ...
Did you make a database of sql server or did you create SQLCE database on the disk?
It looks like though you've tried to create instances of the database .mdf (sql 2014) but you are using a driver for SQLCE .sdf